# Cannot add a new folder in a C++ project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to use a Visual Studio solution to keep my Python as well as CUDA/C++-based projects. As can be seen in the screenshot below, I have **two projects in my solution**, one is C++-based and the other one is Python-based.

[image]

...for the Python-based project, I am getting the option to add a new folder as shown below:

[image]

**PROBLEM:**

For the C++ project (CUDA Runtime template), I am not getting an option to add a new folder. I want to add folders to organize my files.

[image]

***How can I get the option to add folder in C++ project?***

Comment: Is your software up to date? Does this only affect C++ Projects? Do you have enough space left on your storage side?

Comment: yes, the software is up to date. This is a new system with recently installed VS2022, I have   240 GB free space. Yes, only C++ project is affected as I can create a new folder for the python project in the same solution (as shown in the screenshot).

Comment: What heppens when you create the folder with the windows explorer directly in the directory? Will VS2022 recognize it?

Comment: Nah, not in C++ project. Cmake project and some others would. Anything derived from C++ or makefile template wouldn't.

Comment: Visual C++ does not organize its project by folder.  Instead it uses filters, simply grouping of files by function, regardless of its storage.  Like header files vs source files.  There is a good reason for that, beyond it being the way its been done for 30 years, there is a concrete risk of name collisions with one compiled source file overwriting the object file of another.  Producing *very* mysterious linker errors.

Comment: @AhmedAEK: "show all files" did the trick. I remembered that I have used Folders in my C++ projects before and that was exactly the way I did it earlier. Please post your comment as answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on this "show all files" button in the top right corner of the solution explorer then you will be able to see the project folder structure as seen on disk and create new folders.

[image]